# Curl call working in cmd but not in .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pentaho-spoon

Following code is working perfectly fine when ran from cmd, but it fails (Access Denied) when ran as bat from Pentaho DI.

```
curl -k --data "data=username%%3[DUSERNAME]%%26password%%3D[PASSWORD]%%26pid%%3D[1]%%26lid%%3D[2]" https://[...]/export/csv.php -o [...]\output.csv
```

Anything specific I should be aware of? Assuming the issue lies in credentials part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by creating external .bat file and calling it with Pentaho's Shell function. Previously I was implementing the code inside Pentaho (it creates then temp .bat file on run time).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the `%<number>` parts are interpreted as the arguments to the batch file `%1`, `%2`, ...

You can simply double all `%` characters to escape them:

```
curl -k --data "data=username%%%%3[DUSERNAME]%%%%26password%%%%3D[PASSWORD]%%%%26pid%%%%3D[1]%%%%26lid%%%%3D[2]" ...
```